# xampp database backup with 'data' folder

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have mistakenly uninstalled XAMPP without a database backup, but I had copied the 'data' folder, using that can I restore all my databases with a fresh XAMPP installation?

Answer (score 0):

Just install XAMPP and you can replace the **data** folder. There is no problem to load all the databases.